# ESP12 to switch computer power

Tags: switches, esp32, esp8266, npn

**Hi all!**

I'am trying to use an **ESP12S** to turn a desktop computer on/off remotely, using a NPN **2N2222 transistor**, while also trying to keep the physical power button working.

**Much like this project:**

> https://www.ajfriesen.com/pc-switch

Now my background is Computer Science, I had a bit of electronic classes in my Uni, so I've searched a little bit, and I was able to come up with two designs. Pardon if they feel too cumbersome...

First one, a sketch on TinkerCad that simulates the physical pressing of button AND the output from the ESP. I add two buttons to be able simulate **either being pressed** should trigger the **LED ON**.
[link here](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/2rcvq1ql6S4-wol-debug/editel?returnTo=%2Fdashboard&sharecode=Nn6cBOiARjH6eFKsJ0Fil7gZPo4UCg-UkIfwJLs4kKE)

With the success test from the above design ( **LED turned ON by pressing either switch** ) I've tried to **design a PCB on EasyEDA** to actually print it and put it to use.

[image: easyEDA]

Q1: NPN 2N2222 transistor
R2: 200 Ohm resistor
H2: Power switch connection on motherboard
H1: Physical power button

My question is, which is the correct way of using the NPN transistor?

- EX.1
- EX.2

Is there a better way of using the NPN transistor for this particular case?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: It's likely that the NPN won't pull the voltage low enough for the PC to recognize a voltage low

Comment: @VoltageSpike I would have to disagree. At 150mA, Vce is max 300mV. How many amps or how low voltage would suffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ex 1 will not work, it won't do anything.

Ex 2 should work.

The only problem is, you need to know which pin on the motherboard is ground and which is the button input that should be connected to ground to activate it.

Assuming one of the button pins even is a ground. One of them should be, but there is no official standard that defines how the button pins should work, except that there are two pins and pushing the button shorts these two pins together.

Comment: Assuming the non-ground pin is pulled up, it *should* be easy to determine which is which by measuring the voltage across them.

Comment: @vir Yes. Sometimes it reads in the manual.

Comment: @Justme
I will build a prototype on the next days and have it tested. Also, I'll try to measure to know which of the motherboard pins is actually the ground.
Thank you!